# passing a value from a html page using jQuery ajax in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

i'm trying to learn jQuery AJAX in spring MVC and i'm trying to pass a value from a view to a controller and print that value in console from the controller, i would like later learn how to change that value in my controller and then pass it to my view but right now i'm having a  400 Bad Request.

this is my controller methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = "formNormal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formNormal(Model model) {

        return "formNormal";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "formNormal", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String jsonMethod(@RequestBody String name) {

        String controllerVariable  =  name;
        System.out.println("controller variable value is  " + controllerVariable);

        return controllerVariable;
     }
```

and this is my page formNormal.html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



   <script type="text/javascript">

        function doAjaxPost() 
        {
            // get the form values
            var name = $('#name').val();
            var json = {"name" : name};

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "formNormal",
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) 
                            {
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");  
                                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
                            },
                success: function(response) 
                        {
                            alert(response);
                            $('#name').val('');
                        },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                       {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(xhr.responseText);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
            });
        }
        </script>
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Name in view</legend>


        Name in view:   <input type="text" name="name">

        <br>

        <input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()">
  </fieldset>

 <br>
```

EDITED** i change the data to `data: JSON.stringify(json),` and i no longer have the 400 error, i change to the success block to:

```
`success: function(response) 
                        {

                            alert( "Name: "+response);
                            $('#name').val('');
                        },`
```

and it prints me [object Object] in the alert, and in my eclipse console the name variable value is `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `data: JSON.stringify(json)`. You need to convert your javascript variable to JSON String first.

Comment: thanks i dont longer have the 400 error, but now the variable name is empty, my console dont print a value and i get an alert that says "Name: undefined"

Comment: Can you confirm that your controller code gets the value now? The alert is from your success callback so I believe your controller method gets called. Can you please alert(response) in success and let me know?

Comment: i added that line to my succes block like this:  `success: function(response) 
                        {
                            alert( "Name: "+response.name);
                            $('#name').val('');
alert(response)
                        },`
and the alert shows `[object Object]` and my console in eclipse shows that `{}` is the value of my variable

Comment: You didn't get my point. What I am asking you to do is  alert("Name: "+response); instead of alert( "Name: "+response.name); Hope I am clear.

Comment: Try ` $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response)); alert(response);' please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70739/discussion-between-aninda-bhattacharyya-and-stackuser2000).